# System.Web.Mvc 5.2.2.0 vs. 5.2.3.0 versioning issue with aspnet_compiler

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, aspnet-compiler, thinktecture-ident-model

I have problems when turning on compilation of views in Visual Studio. I have a fairly standard ASP.NET MVC 5 application, with a lot of references. I reference System.Web.Mvc 5.2.3.0 (latest as of now), but the compilation seems to have problems with v. 5.2.2.0 vs 5.2.3.0. The excellent tool AsmSpy (https://github.com/mikehadlow/AsmSpy) tells me which assemblies reference which version of System.Web.Mvc:

```
Reference: System.Web.Mvc
   5.1.0.0 by Autofac.Integration.Mvc
   5.0.0.0 by Glimpse.Mvc5
   5.0.0.0 by Microsoft.Web.Mvc
   3.0.0.0 by Mindscape.Raygun4Net.Mvc
   5.2.3.0 by Myrepo.Web.Common
   5.2.3.0 by MyApp
   5.2.2.0 by Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Owin.ResourceAuthorization.Mvc
```

So, the guilty one is Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Owin.ResourceAuthorization.Mvc. But, I have added an Assembly binding redirect to the root web.config of the app, like this:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <!-- lots more -->
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <!-- lots more -->
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

In an effort to try to get to the bottom of the problem, I have turned on Diagnostic build logging, which spits out north of 260,000 lines of log, including:

```
16>  Unified primary reference "System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35". (TaskId:183)
16>      Using this version instead of original version "5.1.0.0" in "C:\Users\ErikBrandstadmoen\Source\Repos\myrepo\packages\Autofac.Mvc5.3.3.4\lib\net45\Autofac.Integration.Mvc.dll" because of a binding redirect entry in the file "obj\Debug\MyWeb.csproj.App.config". (TaskId:183)
16>      Using this version instead of original version "5.0.0.0" in "C:\Users\ErikBrandstadmoen\Source\Repos\myrepo\packages\Glimpse.Mvc5.1.5.3\lib\net45\Glimpse.Mvc5.dll" because of a binding redirect entry in the file "obj\Debug\MyWeb.csproj.App.config". (TaskId:183)
16>      Using this version instead of original version "3.0.0.0" in "C:\Users\ErikBrandstadmoen\Source\Repos\myrepo\packages\Mindscape.Raygun4Net.Mvc.5.1.0\lib\net40\Mindscape.Raygun4Net.Mvc.dll" because of a binding redirect entry in the file "obj\Debug\MyWeb.csproj.App.config". (TaskId:183)
16>      Using this version instead of original version "5.2.2.0" in "C:\Users\ErikBrandstadmoen\Source\Repos\myrepo\packages\Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Owin.ResourceAuthorization.Mvc.2.0.0\lib\net45\Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Owin.ResourceAuthorization.Mvc.dll" because of a binding redirect entry in the file "obj\Debug\MyWeb.csproj.App.config". (TaskId:183)
16>      Using this version instead of original version "5.0.0.0" in "C:\Users\ErikBrandstadmoen\Source\Repos\myrepo\Web\Common\bin\Debug\Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll" because of a binding redirect entry in the file "obj\Debug\MyWeb.csproj.App.config". (TaskId:183)
16>      Resolved file path is "C:\Users\ErikBrandstadmoen\Source\Repos\myrepo\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Mvc.dll". (TaskId:183)
16>      Reference found at search path location "{HintPathFromItem}". (TaskId:183)
16>          For SearchPath "{CandidateAssemblyFiles}". (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\Extensions\NewRelic.Agent.AttributeFilter.dll", but its name "NewRelic.Agent.AttributeFilter" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\Extensions\NewRelic.Agent.Configuration.dll", but its name "NewRelic.Agent.Configuration" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\Extensions\NewRelic.Agent.Core.dll", but its name "NewRelic.Agent.Core" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\Extensions\NewRelic.Agent.LabelsService.dll", but its name "NewRelic.Agent.LabelsService" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\Extensions\NewRelic.Agent.LazyMap.dll", but its name "NewRelic.Agent.LazyMap" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\Extensions\NewRelic.Collections.dll", but its name "NewRelic.Collections" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\Extensions\NewRelic.Core.dll", but its name "NewRelic.Core" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\Extensions\NewRelic.Dispatchers.dll", but its name "NewRelic.Dispatchers" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\Extensions\NewRelic.Memoization.dll", but its name "NewRelic.Memoization" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\Extensions\NewRelic.Providers.CallStack.AsyncLocal.dll", but its name "NewRelic.Providers.CallStack.AsyncLocal" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\Extensions\NewRelic.Providers.TransactionContext.Asp.dll", but its name "NewRelic.Providers.TransactionContext.Asp" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\Extensions\NewRelic.Providers.TransactionContext.Default.dll", but its name "NewRelic.Providers.TransactionContext.Default" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\Extensions\NewRelic.Providers.TransactionContext.Wcf3.dll", but its name "NewRelic.Providers.TransactionContext.Wcf3" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\Extensions\NewRelic.Providers.Wrapper.Asp35.dll", but its name "NewRelic.Providers.Wrapper.Asp35" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\Extensions\NewRelic.Providers.Wrapper.HttpClient.dll", but its name "NewRelic.Providers.Wrapper.HttpClient" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\Extensions\NewRelic.Providers.Wrapper.MongoDb.dll", but its name "NewRelic.Providers.Wrapper.MongoDb" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\Extensions\NewRelic.Providers.Wrapper.Mvc3.dll", but its name "NewRelic.Providers.Wrapper.Mvc3" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\Extensions\NewRelic.Providers.Wrapper.NServiceBus.dll", but its name "NewRelic.Providers.Wrapper.NServiceBus" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\Extensions\NewRelic.Providers.Wrapper.Wcf3.dll", but its name "NewRelic.Providers.Wrapper.Wcf3" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\Extensions\NewRelic.Providers.Wrapper.WebApi1.dll", but its name "NewRelic.Providers.Wrapper.WebApi1" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\Extensions\NewRelic.Providers.Wrapper.WebApi2.dll", but its name "NewRelic.Providers.Wrapper.WebApi2" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\Extensions\NewRelic.Providers.Wrapper.WebOptimization.dll", but its name "NewRelic.Providers.Wrapper.WebOptimization" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\Extensions\NewRelic.Providers.Wrapper.WebServices.dll", but its name "NewRelic.Providers.Wrapper.WebServices" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\Extensions\NewRelic.Reflection.dll", but its name "NewRelic.Reflection" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\Extensions\NewRelic.SystemExtensions.dll", but its name "NewRelic.SystemExtensions" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\Extensions\NewRelic.SystemInterfaces.dll", but its name "NewRelic.SystemInterfaces" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\Extensions\NewRelic.Testing.Assertions.dll", but its name "NewRelic.Testing.Assertions" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\Extensions\NewRelic.Trie.dll", but its name "NewRelic.Trie" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\Extensions\NewRelic.TypeInstantiation.dll", but its name "NewRelic.TypeInstantiation" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\Extensions\NewRelic.WeakActions.dll", but its name "NewRelic.WeakActions" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\NewRelic.Agent.Core.dll", but its name "NewRelic.Agent.Core" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\NewRelic.Agent.Extensions.dll", but its name "NewRelic.Agent.Extensions" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>          Considered "newrelic\NewRelic.Profiler.dll", but its name "NewRelic.Profiler" didn't match. (TaskId:183)
16>      Found related file "C:\Users\ErikBrandstadmoen\Source\Repos\myrepo\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Mvc.xml". (TaskId:183)
16>      The ImageRuntimeVersion for this reference is "v4.0.30319". (TaskId:183)
```

BUT, still, when I compile the views using aspnet_compiler.exe, it complains. And no matter where I put an assembly binding redirect (Applications's root Web.config, Web.config in Views folder), aspnet_compiler.exe doesn't want to respect it. And, it doesn't seem possible to get aspnet_compiler.exe to output anything about what it's actually doing (no log verbosity level settings...)

All I get when compiling the views, is a lot of warnings regarding version 5.2.2.0 vs version 5.2.3.0 of System.Web.Mvc:

```
16>ASPNETCOMPILER : warning CS1702: Assuming assembly reference 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' matches 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35', you may need to supply runtime policy
16>ASPNETCOMPILER : warning CS1702: Assuming assembly reference 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' matches 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35', you may need to supply runtime policy
16>ASPNETCOMPILER : warning CS1702: Assuming assembly reference 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' matches 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35', you may need to supply runtime policy
(lots of more lines)

16>Done executing task "AspNetCompiler". (TaskId:234)
16>Done building target "MvcBuildViews" in project "MyWeb.csproj".: (TargetId:376)
16>Target "Build: (TargetId:377)" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "C:\Users\ErikBrandstadmoen\Source\Repos\myrepo\Web\MyWeb\MyWeb.csproj" (target "Rebuild" depends on it):
16>Done building target "Build" in project "MyWeb.csproj".: (TargetId:377)
16>Target "AfterRebuild: (TargetId:378)" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "C:\Users\ErikBrandstadmoen\Source\Repos\myrepo\Web\MyWeb\MyWeb.csproj" (target "Rebuild" depends on it):
16>Done building target "AfterRebuild" in project "MyWeb.csproj".: (TargetId:378)
16>Target "Rebuild: (TargetId:379)" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "C:\Users\ErikBrandstadmoen\Source\Repos\myrepo\Web\MyWeb\MyWeb.csproj" (entry point):
16>Done building target "Rebuild" in project "MyWeb.csproj".: (TargetId:379)
```

Does anyone have any clues on where to continue troubleshooting? I can of course just ignore the CS1702 warning, but I feel that's like driving with my eyes half closed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try adding the desired assembly version in the Compilation tag in web.config.
`<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" optimizeCompilations="false" tempDirectory="bin\server\Debug">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0 Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>`

Comment: If you are referring to the `Web.config` in the Views folder, it is already there...

Comment: and what about the main web.config? have you tried adding it there as well?

Comment: Also, check if you don't reference 5.2.2.0 in any other places in `web.config`s (maybe one or more got missed when you updated to 5.2.3.0?).

Comment: I *have* thoroughly checked every single .cs,.cshtml,.config,package.config,etc for the value 5.2.2.0 without any hits. And, yes, I have tried the mail web.config.

Comment: I had the same problem recently and finally solved it, check [my solution on stackoverlow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36125730/razor-views-show-warnings-cs1702-after-upgrading-to-microsoft-aspnet-mvc-version)

Comment: I had the same problem recently and finally solved it, check [my solution on stackoverlow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36125730/razor-views-show-warnings-cs1702-after-upgrading-to-microsoft-aspnet-mvc-version)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? My build log is riddled with these error messages, while I've already configured "nowarn" for 1702.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether this will help or not but I had the same problem as you did before I noticed that my main "projectname.csproj" had set its version of Mvc 5.2.3.0 to private and my "projectname.infrastructure.csproj" had set its version to 5.2.2.0. I can only assume that this was the main cause of my version issues.

This is what my "projectname.csproj" looked like before I changed it...

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">    
    <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
    <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

...And this is what it looked like after altering it...

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">    
    <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
    <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

After having done so I rebuilt my solution and debugged my projectname. Since then I havent come across any issues.

Answer (score 1):

I have just had the same issue with the same nuget package where Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Owin.ResourceAuthorization.Mvc is dependant on System.Web.Mvc Version=5.2.2.

I solved this my installing the required version of MVC and then updating the web.config for the project and for the views folder.

The thing that caught me out. is the

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      <add namespace="JQueryUIHelpers" /></namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

I had to downgrade the MVC version for the  type as well.

Comment: So, basically, you downgraded MVC to  5.2.2 to satisfy Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Owin.ResourceAuthorization.Mvc's dependency? But this shouldn't be necessary, should it? Isn't this what assembly binding redirects are for?

Comment: There's an issue about this @ https://github.com/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/issues/149

Comment: I had the same problem recently and finally solved it, check [my solution on stackoverlow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36125730/razor-views-show-warnings-cs1702-after-upgrading-to-microsoft-aspnet-mvc-version)